# Please tell me the simplest datalist paging techniques?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, pagination

I am new to asp.net and I am using datalist, which is configured by `sqldatasource1` and is displaying too many columns as I have written the `select * from image`. But I want only 12 images per page and next button click from 13 to 24 ans so on please tell me the simplest way to do this.

Comment: did you try GOOGLE for that?

Comment: yaa..... but did'nt fount the exact answer

Comment: Here http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/262721/Paging-in-datalist-in-asp-net you will get many solutions.

Comment: Sorry, but how is this an asp.net question? this is purely a "paging in SQL Server" question as i deals with how to construct the SQL side.

Answer (score 0):

How about sending a special parameter to your SQL proc. to retrieve a specific row block for each page request for instance;

Assuming that the page size is 12 records/page then for the page 1 you will need get records which have *rownumber between 1 to 12;* for example;

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY YourColumns) NUM,
   * FROM YOURTABLE
) list
WHERE NUM >1AND NUM <12
```

Comment: Now now how i would increment number n for my next page

Comment: You mean you know zero C# so you are unable to increment a numbers?

Comment: i know how to increemen the numbers but not inside select command